# Regex ignore specific string between two strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

So I have a string like this:

```
test //ita https://example.com lics// test // another // one
```

I can capture text between 2 "//" strings easy enough like so:

```
\/\/(.*?)\/\/
```

Which will return the groups `ita https:` and `test` however I'm trying to get it to ignore the cases where there is a "http://" or "https://".

So I'm trying to get it so that it only returns `ita https://example.com lics` and `another`.

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using? Does it support variable with lookbehinds?

Comment: What would you expect to capture if the string was `https://example.com // abc // def`?

Comment: It's in php, so PCRE I guess? Also it's basically a custom markdown script, so the string can be any length and have any number of "//" strings. So basically like when you do "**bold text**" in markdown. Maybe we'll need to pick a different patter for italics, but hoping there is a way to just ignore the "https?://" string if possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
(https?://)(*SKIP)(*F)|//\s*((?:(?1)|.)*?)\s*//
```

I propose this solution with control verbs [`(*SKIP)` and `(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex).

Here's the [regex101 proof](https://regex101.com/r/4lempJ/1) and [PHP proof](https://3v4l.org/4LcYY)

Comment: Good answer, but it's worth noting that the those backtracking control verbs are implemented only in Perl, PCRE and the Python's pypi regex module. As their use is `tokens_to_discard(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|match_to_keep` the more general solution is to match `tokens_to_discard|(match_to_keep)`but keep only captures.

Comment: The asker has declared the implementation of the pattern will be in PHP via a comment. So I added that tag to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to match your strings:

```
(?<!https:|http:)//\s*((?:https?://|(?!//).)*)(?<!\s)\s*//
```

This will match:

- `(?<!https:|http:)//` : `//`, not preceded by `https:` or `http:`
- `\s*` : some amount of whitespace
- `((?:https?://|(?!//).)+)` : capture group 1, some number of either:

  - `https?://` : `//` preceded by `https:` or `http:`; or
  - `(?!//).` : a character which is not the start of `//`
- `(?<!\s)\s*` : some amount of whitespace, not preceded by whitespace (this prevents capturing any whitespace before the closing `//` in group 1)
- `//` : literal `//`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nLak51/1)

The strings you are interested in will be captured in group 1. In PHP:

```php
$text = 'test //ita https://example.com lics// test // another // one';
$regex = '~(?<!https:|http:)//\s*((?:https?://|(?!//).)*)(?<!\s)\s*//~';
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
var_export($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'ita https://example.com lics',
  1 => 'another',
)
```

PHP demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rn1Gi)

Comment: @Thefourthbird, when splashing in a local pool a friend told me Amsterdam gets 190 days per year (but not so much most days), so if that's where you live getting out of the rain would be quite a common occurrence. Why is `\s*` in your regex needed?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think to omit the whitespace chars  from the capture group value, but you can also omit it if all the text should be in group 1. The rain is getting better now, but at the end of last year it rained for like 2 months and we probably broke another weather record. Let me clean up these comments.

Comment: @Thefourthbird based on the question I probably want to exclude those trailing spaces from the match (OP wants `another`, not `another ` from the first string. So perhaps a non-greedy match is better https://regex101.com/r/3mLJmP/1

Comment: Or perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/nLak51/1 I am going to get some sleep, good luck!

Comment: @Thefourthbird nice! I've incorporated that into the answer. thanks - hope you sleep well.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your on the right track.

```
(?<!https?:\/\/)\/\/(.*?)(?=(?:\s|https?:\/\/|$))
```

Heres how it works

> ```
> (?<!https?:\/\/)
> ```
>
> Negative lookbehind assertion to ensure that there is no "http://" or
> "https://" before "//".
>
> ```
> \/\/
> ```
>
> Matches the "//" strings.
>
> ```
> (.*?)
> ```
>
> Captures any text between "//" using a non-greedy match.
>
> ```
> (?=(?:\s|https?:\/\/|$))
> ```
>
> Positive lookahead assertion to ensure that what follows is either a
> whitespace character, "http://" or "https://", or the end of the
> string.

You should post a few string examples to better test but based on what I tried, looks like this works.

Comment: Thx Patrick, getting some mixed results with this, I should have noted that the string can be any length with any number of "//". Here it is: https://regex101.com/r/q7BZ0b/1

Answer (score -1):

Just to show another implemented solution, I'll demonstrate `preg_split()` instead of `preg_match_all()` so that the isolated strings are immediately returned from the native function call instead of accessing a reference variable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hXihR))

```
var_export(
    preg_split(
        '~(?1)(?://\s*((?:https?://|.)*?)\s*//)?~',
        $text,
        -1,
        PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'ita https://example.com lics',
  1 => 'another',
)
```

Breakdown:

```
(?1)                  #match subpattern logic from capture group 1 ("non-marker" characters -- in this context)
(?:                   #start non-capturing group
   //                 #two literal forward slashes
   \s*                #zero or more whitespace characters
   (                  #start capture group 1
      (?:             #start non-capturing group
         https?://    #match http:// or https://
         |            #OR
         .            #match a single character
      )*?             #end non-capturing group and lazily match zero or more repetitions of the pattern
   )                  #end capture group 1
   \s*                #zero or more whitespace characters
   //                 #two literal forward slashes
)?                    #close non-capturing group and allow zero or one repetition
```

Comment: Can anyone explain the problem with this explained and working answer?